# Protecting subfolders of different parent folders with web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config

My asp.net application stores PDF and Word files in many subfolders that are inside a root folder named "Documentos".

However, those subfolders are created according to some determined rules.

Example of subfolders:

```
\Documentos\11\Asiento\
\Documentos\12\Resol\
\Documentos\24\Asiento\
\Documentos\33\Resol\
.. and so on.
```

What I need is to protect only subfolder "Asiento" from unauthenticated access. As you see, subfolder Asiento is not right down from folder Documentos. Its parent folder is a subfolder named with a number.

I don't know if web.config allows to protect any subfolder named Asiento.

I tried this setting, putting a tilde ~ character in order to scope only subfolders named "Asiento"

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>

<location path="~/Asiento"  >
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
</location>
```

But it didn't make any success. Any unauthenticated user can access any file inside subfolder Asiento.

What it works is when I put "Documentos" as root folder, but it restrict everything inside it.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>

<location path="Documentos"  >
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
</location>
```

Is it possible what I'm looking for?

Comment: why can't you have unauthorized folders list in config and check the same in c#/vb code before giving access for others to write/read/create or delete?

Comment: I thought you could only restrict access through web.config. Restrict access to load a file like: `http://MyHost/MyWebapp/Documentos/11/Asiento/xyz.pdf`